# Intuition for linear independence after subtracting identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently working on a problem where I need to show that for an arbitrary matrix, A with all entries $0 < A_{i,j} < 1$ and the entries in each row summing to $1$, $\operatorname{null}(A - I_n)$ has dimension 1.

In my current approach, I would like to employ the rank nullity theorem. In specific, since all the rows sum to 1, we can write the columns as a linear combination of one another. Hence, we know that $\operatorname{rank}(A - I) \leq n-1$. Currently, however, I'm struggling to say that $n-1$ columns in $A - I$ are linearly independent.

Intuitively, it seems to me like this should be true for any set of $n - 1$ columns for the following reasons:

- Say the values in the other $(n-1)$ columns in $A$ are generated according to some linear relationship. Then, subtracting the identity matrix perturbs this relationship since one of the $n$ rows in the $(n-1)$ columns will not contain $a -1$ term but all the others will from this subtraction.
- Additionally, subtracting the identity matrix will not create a linear relationship among $(n-1)$ columns in $A$ it is simply a translation of each column vector.

Is this intuition on the right track? If so, what can I do to help formalize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the Perron Frobenius theorem.

Let $e$ be the vector of ones. Clearly $Ae=e$ so $\ker (A-I)$ has dimension at least one.

Suppose $x$ is **not** in the span of $e$, then note that
$\min_k [Ax]_k > \min x_k$ and $\max_k [Ax]_k < \max x_k$.

So, now suppose $Ax = x$, then the above shows that $x$ **must** lie in the span of $e$.

Hence $\dim \ker (A-I) = 1$.

Comment: To be sure I'm understanding correctly, even though we get that both $\min_ []_ >min_ $  and $\max_ []_ < max_ $, we really only need one of these to ensure that $Ax \neq x$, correct? Since $\min_ []_ >min_ $ alone is sufficient to imply that $ \neq x$

Comment: Correct, but the above also shows how $A^n x$ converges to something in the space of $e$. Basically one is the dominant eigenvalue.